# In ReactJS, heading tag is not being read by SEO tool

Tags: reactjs

I have been developing a website on ReactJS which is SEO-centric. Regardless of all my previous attempts, my header tag is not being read by SEO tools. Below is my code:

```
<div className="homepage-slides owl-carousel">
  <div className="home-slider-1">
    <img src="assets/images/slider1.png" className=" d-lg-none d-none-block" />
    <div className="container-fluid">
      <div className="row slider-one">
        <div className="col-lg-5 offset-lg-1 col-md-12 pt-5 pr-1 pl-1">
          <div className="d-flex align-items-justify flex-column">
            <div className="banner-line1 pt-5 d-none d-lg-block"> Empowering Small Businesses with Cloud
            </div>
            <div className="banner-line1 pt-1 d-lg-none d-none-block">Empowering Small Businesses with Cloud
            </div>
            <h1 className="banner-line-2">For Seamless Collaboration and High Business Availability with
              Enterprise-grade Security</h1>
            <div className="main-banner-text">Manage your Key Operations from Anywhere</div>
            <div className="pt-4 pb-3">
              <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#freedemoModal" className="btn button btn-get-started mb-1"> Free Demo</a>&nbsp;
              <a href="trial.html" className="btn button btn-get-freetrail mb-1">Get Free Trial</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="col-lg-6 col-md-12 img-slider-one d-none d-lg-block  pr-1 pl-1" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Try using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-helmet.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. I believe h1 tags from index.html are the only ones that will get detected in seo analysis.

Comment: We figured it out. We had to use NextJS to make it SEO friendly.